# Unable to retrieve XForms engine state

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I working with Orbeon XForms 4.7 on eXist-db 2.2. We've always had session problems where a session would expire in eXist-db after a given point in time, but where Orbeon retains a session token and 'thinks' it is still logged on. This may or may not be at the heart of what I see in the logging:

```
2016-11-07 15:06:27,643 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Received request
2016-11-07 15:06:27,650 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Timing: 7
2016-11-07 15:06:29,368 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Received request
2016-11-07 15:06:29,372 ERROR XFormsServer  - Unable to retrieve XForms engine state. Please reload the current page. Note that you will lose any unsaved changes. {}
2016-11-07 15:06:29,372 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Timing: 4
2016-11-07 15:06:29,373 ERROR ProcessorService  - 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Unable to retrieve XForms engine state. Please reload the current page. Note that you will lose any unsaved changes.  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/config/prologue-servlet.xpl                                                  |executing processor           |  36|
|······················································································································|
|element=<p:processor name="oxf:pipeline">[...]</p:processor>                                                          |
|name   ={http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors}pipeline                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/ops/xforms/xforms-server.xpl                                                 |reading processor output      |  43|
|······················································································································|
|element=<p:output name="response" id="xforms-response"/>                                                              |
|name   =response                                                                                                      |
|id     =xforms-response                                                                                               |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.OXFException                                                                         |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.state.XFormsStateManager     |createDocumentFromStore       |XFormsStateManager.java       | 489|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.state.XFormsStateManager     |findOrRestoreDocument         |XFormsStateManager.java       | 448|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.state.XFormsStateManager     |beforeUpdate                  |XFormsStateManager.java       | 328|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer       |doIt                          |XFormsServer.java             | 169|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer       |access$000                    |XFormsServer.java             |  59|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer$1     |readImpl                      |XFormsServer.java             |  85|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.common.OrbeonLocationException$     |wrapException                 |OrbeonLocationException.scala |  60|
|org.orbeon.oxf.common.OrbeonLocationException      |wrapException                 |OrbeonLocationException.scala |    |
```

This error comes up every such and so seconds. There is no mention what XForms triggers it, so a targeted search is out of the question.

Does anyone know how to interpret this error and possibly how to prevent it? Note that there's no error at the user side at all, and everything appears to work fine. This is purely server side.

Comment: Alexander, 4.7 is super-old, and it will be hard for us to help you with this here. It is possible that you're hitting a bug that has been fixed since then. Would you be able to update newer version of Orbeon Forms? -Alex

Comment: FYI @avernet I have been in touch with Alexander about issues upgrading.

Comment: Now this said, this error seems to just indicate an expired session. Is Orbeon Forms called directly from the browser here?

Comment: We create sessions in Orbeon as we login into eXist-db. The Orbeon session remains active unless you leave the browser window idle for a period of time unknown to me. The browser apparently knows when it is idle as the form stops responding at that time (for most of it at least).
The call you happening is from a polling thing in one of our forms, that checks to see if there is any news message to display (e.g. maintenance, important update)